# Emacs: Yanking not working when executing a macro

Tags: emacs, ubuntu-9.04

When recording a macro, if I perform any kind of kill (backward-kill-word), followed by a yank , the macro stops execution at the point of the yank and exits. Nothing I do seems to work to be able to actually yank something in a macro.
I'm running emacs 22 on Ubuntu 9.04.

Comment: I should say I can define the macro just fine, but when it comes to executing it, yanking fails and the execution stops.

Comment: Can you provide an example?  Works for me just fine (23.1).  Also, try reproducing the problem when starting up w/out customizations (`emacs -q --no-site-file`).

Comment: Even something as easy:  
Hello, there  
Defining the macro to search for the ',' then kill-word (killing 'there'), moving to beginning of line and yanking, ending definition.
This works just fine during definition, but as soon as I try to execute the macro I get:
hello,   
with the cursor at the beginning of the word. 'there' is killed, but not yanked.  
I tried this as you said with -q --no-site-file, and it works.

Comment: Interesting...even in my scratch buffer this is working properly. I guess I'll have to narrow down which mode is futzing this up. Thanks for the tip, never knew about --no-site-file.

Comment: Ruby mode is hosing this, and it's highly annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby mode appears to be the culprit here. When I disable ruby mode, this works like a charm.